# output from console app and read output from a forms app c#

Tags: c#, processstartinfo

So i have two applications.
In the console app let's say i do `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");`
I then compile to an exe.

From my main forms application i want to call this application

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\ConsoleApp1.exe",
                Arguments = "Arguments",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };
            var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
            var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(output);
```

However, it does not read the output. Is there another way i should output from the console app rather than `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");`

Comment: Why do you need to do this, since you are building both applications, just use shared libraries, or IPC

Comment: I will not be calling it from c# necessarily but i have the same issue when calling the .exe from python. Whenever i use console.writeline it does not seem to register as a standard output from another proces in c# or python for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that you are reading the output before the command finishes. Change the sequence where you are reading the result **after** completion

```
var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

Comment: Still had the same issue

Comment: Besides standardoutput, redirect errorOutput to see if there are errors